# ROM/MOD for pure Android experience

Tags: rom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)

I'm looking for a Mod or Rom for a HTC Desire S and a Motorola Xoom which provides the cleanest Android experience without modifications. Similar to that of the Nexus range of phones. Eventually, I'd like to put ICS on both of these devices.

Comment: The Xoom is already as "pure Honeycomb" as it gets. It's the tablet equivalent of the Nexus line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As elderathis said, the Xoom is a pure android device, as for the Desire S, I believe that [CyanogenMod is available](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/devices/htc-desire-s) for that device. It is "pure android", plus some additional tweaks after.